# Predictions in recorded video using object detection tensorflow API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to read a video file (using opencv), loop over all frames using tensorflow's object-detection API to do the predictions and bounding boxes, and writing the predicted frames (with boxes) to a new video file. I used the object_detection_tutorial.ipynb with some modifications to capture the video frames and process it in faster-rcnn-inception-resnet-v2 loaded from a frozen graph (after trained).

I am using a tesla P100 gpu in a cloud machine with windows 10 and 56GB ram. Also using tensorflow-gpu.

When I run the code, it takes 0,5 second per frame. Is it a normal speed for a tesla P100 or I am doing something wrong in the code to make it slower?

This code is just a test, as later I will have to use it in a real time video prediction task. If 0,5 second per frame is an expected speed using tensorflow API, I think I will cannot use it in my task :(

So, after running it, i get the following running times

processing frame number 1.0

time to capture video frame 0.0

time to predict 0.49225664138793945

time to generate boxes in a frame 0.14833950996398926

time to write a frame in video file 0.04687023162841797

total time in the loop 0.6874663829803467

As you guys can see, the code using the CPU (opencv) goes fast. But when I use the GPU, it takes almost 0,5 seconds just in prediction task (used in sess.run).

Any advices? Thank you in advance. Bellow follows my code

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import six.moves.urllib as urllib
    import sys
    import tarfile
    import tensorflow as tf
    import zipfile
    import time

```
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
from imutils import paths

import re

#This is needed since the code is stored in the object_detection    folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.9.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.9.* or later!')


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

#Detection using tensorflow inside write_video function

def write_video():

    filename = 'output/teste_v2.avi'
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('W', 'M', 'V', '2')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('pneu_trim2.mp4')
    framerate = round(cap.get(5),2)
    w = int(cap.get(3))
    h = int(cap.get(4))
    resolution = (w, h)

    VideoFileOutput = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, framerate, resolution)    

    ################################
    # # Model preparation 

    # ## Variables
    # 
    # Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH` to point to a new .pb file.  
    # 


    # What model to download.
    MODEL_NAME = 'training/pneu_incep_step_24887'
    print("loading model from " + MODEL_NAME)

    # Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
    PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

    # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
    PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'object-detection.pbtxt')

    NUM_CLASSES = 5


    # ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

    time_graph = time.time()
    print('loading graphs')
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
      od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    print("tempo build graph = " + str(time.time() - time_graph))

    # ## Loading label map

    label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
    categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
    category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

    ################################

    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            while (cap.isOpened()):
              time_loop = time.time()
              print('processing frame number: ' + str(cap.get(1)))
              time_captureframe = time.time()
              ret, image_np = cap.read()
              print("time to capture video frame = " + str(time.time() - time_captureframe))
              if (ret != True):
                  break
              # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
              # result image with boxes and labels on it.
              #image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
              # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
              image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
              image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
              # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
              boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
              # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
              # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
              scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
              classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
              num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
              # Actual detection.
              time_prediction = time.time()
              (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                  [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                  feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
              print("time to predict = " + str(time.time() - time_prediction))
              # Visualization of the results of a detection.
              time_visualizeboxes = time.time()
              vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                  image_np,
                  np.squeeze(boxes),
                  np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                  np.squeeze(scores),
                  category_index,
                  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                  line_thickness=8)
              print("time to generate boxes in a frame = " + str(time.time() - time_visualizeboxes))


              time_writeframe = time.time()
              VideoFileOutput.write(image_np)
              print("time to write a frame in video file = " + str(time.time() - time_writeframe))

              print("total time in the loop = " + str(time.time() - time_loop))

    cap.release()
    VideoFileOutput.release()
    print('done')
```

Comment: I don't think we can tell you if you are doing something wrong in the code if you don't include the code in your question.

Comment: Any modern computer is usually faster and can capture multiple frames in a second. Here is a sample if you are thinking if you are doing it wrong - https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: Thanks @MatiasValdenegro. I added the code and more details about the performance. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: And thanks @SrinivasBringu, but as we can see in the details I added, the opencv functions are running really fast. the problem is in tensorflow model prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with the model you were using.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md
Basically the model Faster-rcnn-inception-resnet-v2 will take more time.
You can refer the link to know the speed for the model

Comment: That's true. After choosing other models, the inference speed changes dramaticallly.